# Django save many to many relationship on custom many to many model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Trying to set values for a custom many to many model in Django. My User model has a many to many field named as dispatcher_county. I have created a model to handle many to many relationship between user's who are dispatchers and counties named as DispatcherCounty. Check the create method in UserPostSerializer mentioned below to see how I am creating users who are dispatchers and drivers.

Error Received:

> AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute
> '_m2m_reverse_name_cache'

requirements:

```
Django==3.0.8
djangorestframework==3.11.0
mysqlclient==2.0.1
```

model.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    """ 
    This is a class for user table which overrides functionalities of default django user model.
      
    Attributes: 
        name (CharField): Name of a user.
        email (EmailField): Email address of a user. 
        mobile (CharField): Phone number of a user.
        date_joined (CharField): When a user was added.
        last_login (CharField): Last login date time of a user.
        is_admin (CharField): If user is a admin or not.
        is_active (CharField): If user is active or not.
        is_staff (CharField): If user is staff or not.
        is_superuser (CharField): If user is a superuser or not.
        role (OneToOneField): One to one relationship with role table.
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(
                regex=r"^\d{10,14}$",
                message="Phone number must be entered in format: '+999999999'. Up to 14 digits allowed.",
            )
        ],
        max_length=15,
        unique=True,
    )
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    dispatcher_counties = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self",
        through="DispatcherCounty",
        symmetrical=False,
        related_name="dispatcher_has_county",
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "mobile"

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email", "name"]

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email + ", " + self.mobile + ", " + self.name

    # For checking permissions. to keep it simple all admin have ALL permissons
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    # Does this user have permission to view this app? (ALWAYS YES FOR SIMPLICITY)
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)


class DispatcherDriver(models.Model):
    dispatcher = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="dispatcher_driver"
    )
    driver = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="driver_dispatcher"
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "dispatcher_driver"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dispatcher.name + ", " + self.driver.name


class DispatcherCounty(models.Model):
    dispatcher = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="dispatcher_county"
    )
    county = models.ForeignKey(
        County, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="county_dispatcher"
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "dispatcher_county"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dispatcher.name + ", " + self.county.name
```

serializer.py

```
class UserPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=80)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    mobile = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=15,)
    role = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    dispatcher = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    counties = serializers.ListField(
        required=False,
        child=serializers.IntegerField(),
        error_messages={"required": "Counties field is required."},
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ["password"]

    def validate(self, data):
        # if role is driver
        if data["role"].name == "Driver":
            # dispatcher is required
            if "dispatcher" not in data.keys() or data["dispatcher"] is None:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    "Dispatcher field is required if role is Driver."
                )
            else:
                try:
                    dispatcher = User.objects.filter_superuser().get(
                        pk=data["dispatcher"]
                    )

                    if dispatcher.role.name != "Dispatcher":
                        raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid dispatcher.")

                    data["dispatcher"] = dispatcher

                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    raise serializers.ValidationError("Dispatcher not found.")
        # if role is dispatcher
        elif data["role"].name == "Dispatcher":
            # counties are required
            if (
                "counties" not in data.keys()
                or data["counties"] is None
                or len(data["counties"]) == 0
            ):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    "Counties field is required if role is Dispatcher. Min 1 county is required."
                )

        return data

    def validate_role(self, value):
        role = Role.objects.filter(name=value).exclude(name__iexact="Superuser").first()
        if role is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Not a valid role.")

        return role

    def validate_email(self, value):
        user = User.objects

        if self.instance:
            user = user.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)

        if user.filter(email__iexact=value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User with this email already exists.")

        return value

    def validate_mobile(self, value):
        if validate_phone_number(value) is None:

            user = User.objects

            if self.instance:
                user = user.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)

            if user.filter(mobile__iexact=value):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    "User with this phone number already exists."
                )

        return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                dispatcher = None
                if validated_data["role"].name == "Driver":
                    dispatcher = validated_data.pop("dispatcher")

                counties = None
                if validated_data["role"].name == "Dispatcher":
                    counties = validated_data.pop("counties")

                instance = User.objects.create(**validated_data)

                if dispatcher is not None:
                    DispatcherDriver.objects.create(
                        dispatcher=dispatcher, driver=instance
                    )

                if counties is not None:
                    counties = County.objects.filter(id__in=counties).all()

                    if len(counties) == 0:
                        raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid counties.")

                    instance.dispatcher_counties.set(*counties)

            return instance
        except DatabaseError as database_error:
            return None
```

Comment: You set the Many to Many field to `'self'` that means it is in a many to many relationship with itself. Yet there is only one foreign key to user in the through model. Did you mean to set the many to many field to `County`?

Comment: Yes, I want many to many relation between users and counties